# How to vertical align in price table

Tags: css, css-float

We want to display li elements in vertical align center. any idea?

my css is

```
.pricing-table ul{border-radius:3px;width:160px;text-align:center;float:left;background-color:#FFF;border-color:#CCC;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;margin:3px;padding:0}
.pricing-table ul li{background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:0;list-style:none!important;min-height:58px;border-color:#B83737;border-width:2px;padding:5px}
.pricing-table li:nth-child(odd){background-color:#fff}
.pricing-table ul .heading{color:#000;background-color:#d5d8dd;font-weight:700;font-size:16px}
.pricing-table ul .price{font-weight:700}
```

my html code

```
    <div id="pricing-table" class="pricing-table">
<ul><li>Shimla</li><li>Manali</li><li>Dharamshala, Delhi, Manali, Shimla</li><li>Dalhousie</li><li>Chandigarh</li><li>Delhi</li></ul>
<ul><li>Shimla</li><li>Manali</li><li>Dharamshala</li><li>Dalhousie</li><li>Chandigarh, Delhi, Manali, Shimla</li><li>Delhi</li></ul>                      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove **min-height: 58px;** css property in **.pricing-table ul li**
and set **padding** property from **5px to 25px**

```
.pricing-table ul li{
    padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: suresh I would suggest to remove `!important` while you using specificity here. Also it make CSS invalid.

Comment: I implemented the procedure as you said, but each and every cells in the column are not even, especially in the vertical alignment, just like in the image shown http://s23.postimg.org/re61q2td7/screen.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First thought ... why not using a table?

Second thought ... use table css display properties, then you can use vertical align middle to center the text.

Downside ... I wrapped the text inside a span element ... and used display table, table-row and table-cell to get the correct result.

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yoeri/TgX2h/)

**Css:**

```
.pricing-table ul {
    display: table;
    ...
}
.pricing-table ul li {
    display:table-row;
    ...
}
.pricing-table ul li span {
    display: table-cell;   
    height:58px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```